# I can't seem to get the datafield i want from an object in a TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview

This is the code for the TableView:

```
TableView<KontaktPerson> tableKontaktPerson = new TableView<>();
TableColumn KontaktPersonFornavn = new TableColumn("Fornavn");
KontaktPersonFornavn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<KontaktPerson, String>("fornavn"));

TableColumn KontaktPersonEtternavn = new TableColumn("Etternavn");
KontaktPersonEtternavn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<KontaktPerson, String>("etternavn"));

TableColumn KontaktPersonNr = new TableColumn("Medlemsnummer");
KontaktPersonNr.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<KontaktPerson, Integer>("medlemsNr"));

tableKontaktPerson.getColumns().addAll(KontaktPersonFornavn,KontaktPersonEtternavn,KontaktPersonNr);
tableKontaktPerson.getSelectionModel().cellSelectionEnabledProperty();
tableKontaktPerson.setPrefSize(800, 300);
```

i wish to display the "fornavn","etternavn" and "medlemsNr" of that Object

Here is the "KontaktPerson" Class:

```
public class KontaktPerson extends Bruker implements Serializable {
private String fornavn, etternavn, telefon, epost;
private static int nestenr = 1000;
private int medlemsNr;

public KontaktPerson(String br, String pas, String fn, String en, String tlf, String ep) { // Tar in oppgitte Stirng verdier
    super(br,pas);
    fornavn = fn;
    etternavn = en;
    telefon = tlf;
    epost = ep;
    medlemsNr = ++nestenr;

}
}
```

For some reason i cant seem to get the "fornavn" and "etternavn" out, i just get the medlemsNr...

Comment: The `new PropertyValueFactory<KontaktPerson, String>("fornavn")` will look for `getFornavn()` or `isFornavn()` methods of `KontaktPerson`. Be sure that they exist.

Comment: nevermind i found out that i had to declare fornavn and etternavn as SimpleStringProperty instead of String